# Program prints twice after user input restarts the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, exception, conditional-statements

The print functions after the conditional statements are printing twice when user input results in an error that is excepted and restarts the program. I don't see where I call the variable twice.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def start():
    concept = ("Concept: ")
    global grade
    while True:
        try:
            grade = float(input("something: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("please type numbers")
            start()
            break
        finally:
            if grade > 100:
                print("grade exceeds")
                start()
                break
            elif grade < 0:
                print("grade deficit")
                start()
                break
            elif grade >= 90 and grade <= 100:
                print(concept + "A")
            elif grade >= 80 and grade <= 89:
                print(concept + "B")
            elif grade >= 70 and grade <= 79:
                print(concept + "C")
            elif grade >= 60 and grade <= 69:
                print(concept + "D")
            elif grade >= 0 and grade <= 59:
                print(concept + "F")
            else:
                pass

start()
```

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Don't use recursion for input validation.

Comment: Please provide the input that causes the wrong output, and the output that it causes.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  Include your test data as part of the program, and trace the execution and data flow properly.  See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.

Comment: Since you're printing the results in the `finally:` block, it gets printed whether or not the exception occurred.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: So when you recurse because of the exception, the recursive call prints the results, then it returns and the results get printed again.

Comment: There's also no reason for the `while True:` loop, since you always break out of it.

Comment: Hello. I only want to accept numbers, that's why I use float. So I use the except thingy to hide the error and restart the program. Also, if the number is below zero and over 100 the program should restart. Anyway, if any of this happens and the user inputs a valid number (between 0 and 100), it will print "concept" twice. If the users starts the program and straight up inputs a valid number, it will not print "concept" twice. Should I add this comment to my main post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the code that prints the results in the `finally()` block. That executes whether or not there was an exception, so when the recursive call returns it executes that code again. It should be in the `try` block so it will be skipped when there's an error.

There's also no need for the `while` loop, since you're always breaking out of it; you're using recursion to repeat it.

`grade` doesn't need to be a global variable.

You shouldn't have tests like `and grade <= 89`. The previous `elif` already ensures that it's less than `90`. Your tests leave cases like `89.5` out of the ranges (if you're only entering whole numbers, use `int()` rather than `float()`).

```
def start():
    concept = ("Concept: ")
    try:
        grade = float(input("something: "))
        if grade > 100:
            print("grade exceeds")
            start()
            break
        elif grade < 0:
            print("grade deficit")
            start()
            break
        elif grade >= 90:
            print(concept + "A")
        elif grade >= 80:
            print(concept + "B")
        elif grade >= 70:
            print(concept + "C")
        elif grade >= 60:
            print(concept + "D")
        else:
            print(concept + "F")
    except ValueError:
        print("please type numbers")
        start()

start()
```

But more generally, you shouldn't use recursion like this, just use a loop.

```
def start():
    concept = "Concept: "
    while True:
        try:
            grade = float(input("something: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please type numbers")
    if grade > 100:
        print("grade exceeds")
        start()
        break
    elif grade < 0:
        print("grade deficit")
        start()
        break
    elif grade >= 90:
        print(concept + "A")
    elif grade >= 80:
        print(concept + "B")
    elif grade >= 70:
        print(concept + "C")
    elif grade >= 60:
        print(concept + "D")
    else:
        print(concept + "F")
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. I did something like this and it solved my problem.
I think the problem is that I did what you said and also called the start function AFTER the block. Anyways, it's running well.

Answer (score 0):

Your `start()` function is recursive each time that your `Except` block executes. Since `grade` is a global variable and `finally` blocks always run even when exception blocks execute, you'll get a number of repeating print statements equal to the number of times that the exception block executed.

In other words, if an error is raised, and then the user inputs some valid input, then the rest of your `finally` block triggers a second time with that original input. Because the `finally` block will always trigger, even after an exception was raised.